# Using and updating a variable across different intents

Tags: android, variables, android-intent

this is my first question being asked on stackoverflow. My question is regarding variable use across different recyclable intents.

e is declared like this.

```
final Bundle e=getIntent().getExtras();
```

Here i am creating new intents for different setOnClickListener() and passing a different variable for each intent.

```
            Intent info = new Intent(EItemListView.this, ItemInfo.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            int[] a=new int[listview.getAdapter().getCount()];
            if (i == 0) {
                extras.putIntArray("img", n5x_images);
                extras.putString("info", n5x_info);
                extras.putInt("pc",a[0]);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                extras.putIntArray("img", op3_images);
                extras.putString("info", op3_info);
                extras.putInt("pc",a[1]);
            }
            info.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(info);
```

Now this is the OnClickListener() where i am trying to update the variables which i passed through the intent extras, but am unable to update those variables.

```
addtc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int c=e.getInt("pc");
            c=c+1;
            Log.i("Log","value "+c);
        }
```

The log message which i get from the above method is always 1, i think the variable in c is always set to 0 and then increments by 1 and hence the log message shows 1.
I need the variables a[0],a[1],a[2], etc to pertain its increment operation.

To make it more clear, this is the java file i am using. The error is in the OnClickListener of addtc button at the bottom of this code.

```
public class ItemInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewAnimator viewanimator;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_info);

    Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bnext);
    Button prev=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bprev);
    viewanimator=(ViewAnimator)findViewById(R.id.viewAnimator);
    TextView info=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_info);
    Button addtc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.badd);
    Button test=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    Bundle e=getIntent().getExtras();
    int img[]=e.getIntArray("img");


    for(int i=0;i<img.length;i++)
    {
        ImageView imgview = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imgview.setImageResource(img[i]);
        viewanimator.addView(imgview);
    }

    info.setText(e.getString("info"));

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewanimator.showNext();
        }
    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewanimator.showPrevious();
        }
    });

    addtc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int c=e.getInt("pc");
            c=c++;
            Log.i("Log","value "+c);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `int c=e.getInt("pc");` where are you initializing e?

Comment: And did you try to debug your code at the place where you are adding value to bundle?

Comment: by debugging, which value is the a[0] or a[1] before passing intent?

Comment: sorry for that, i made the edit to show the declaration of e.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley the value of a[0] and a[1] etc is always passed as 0 when the intent is opened.

Comment: Yep, I mean before opening intent. When you use putInt, which is their value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. You cannot do this in this way. Your understanding of what an "extra" in an `Intent` is incorrect.

When you do this:

```
            extras.putInt("pc",a[1]);
```

This adds an "extra" to the extras `Bundle`. The `Bundle` is simply a key/value pair map and you have added an entry that contains the key `"pc"` and the value is whatever `a[1]` is. It puts **a copy of the value of `a[1]`** into the `Bundle`, it does not put a **reference to `a[1]`** in the `Bundle`.

Therefore, if `a[1]` is 5 when you add it to the extras `Bundle`, `a[1]` will always be 5 and will never be changed to anything else.

You can't do this in this way.

Alternative: Depending on your application architecture and what you are trying to do, you can use one of the following methods:

1) Use `startActivityForResult()`, pass the data from one `Activity` to another, have the second `Activity` update the data and put it back into the `Intent` which is then returned to the "calling" `Activity` by using `setResult()`.

2) Use a `static` variable (basically a "global" variable) to contain the data. Both activities can then access the data directly (you don't need to put the data in the `Intent`.

3) Put the data in a database. Both activities can then read/write from/to the database.

Comment: I still could not reach a solution to this problem, I have a listView with some items and each item starts a new intent on every OnClickListener(), so i need a separate variable for each intent opened via the OnClickListener().

Comment: You don't need a different variable for each item. You just need a unique index for each item. This index is used to access the data assocated with that item. You can keep this data in a static `ArrayList`, or in a database, or you can send the data associated with one item back and forth using `startActivityForResult()` as long as you include the item index, you'll know to which item the data belongs.

Comment: i'm still stuck at this, i tried a few different things but could'nt get the desired result. I want to achieve the following functionality, the list of items opens up and then every listitem has an OnClickListener which would pen a new intent for each item, now that intent has an "Add to Cart" button which should add that specific item to the cart. Now, when the cart activity is opened, all those items should be present in which "Add to Cart" button was pressed

Answer (score 0):

First advice I can give you is **debugging** **and** **posting debug result**. for example, are you sure that `a[0]` and `a[1]` aren't `0`?

Assuming they are not, why are you declaring the `bundle` as `final`? [referring to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4556562/4700782) probably `final` is not what you were looking for. Try removing it or replacing with `private`

Another suggestion is more for readable purpose, replace `c = c+1;` with `c++;` but **this doesn't change the result**, it just make it more linear and easier for reading.

Now after this fix (the final keyword one) tell me if something changed please :)

Comment: the final keyword is there beacause 'e' is getting accessed from  innerclass.

Comment: @Androidjack-RajeshGosemath protected or public are also ok.. Final keyword disable setters, so I think this might cause the problem. Have you tried removing it as i said?